# How to find SQL Server database files in application files when the project is published in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013, setup-project

I'm trying to make a setup for my Visual Studio 2013 project and I'm using SQL Server database connected to it.

I'm trying to publish it with the normal way but when I'm checking the applications file:

[image]

I don't see any of my database file (the `.mdf` and the `.ldf` file):

[image]

I tried to add them manually to the debug folder in the project but still the same.

Here's my connection string in `App.config` :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB_Maintenance.Properties.Settings.Setting" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-LQV6N5B\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Clinic_DB;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there any way I could make them show? Or is there any way to make a setup for the project and database within to be able to run it on any computer?

Comment: You won't see any; you're connecting the SQL Server Express, which is a completely separate installation to Visual Studio. Express has the database files, not your application.

Comment: @Larnu the tutorials i have watched on setup project with database were using this method and they were able to see the 2 files of the database (.mdf and .ldf) in the application files! what is the deference in my case?

Comment: I *assume* that the tutorial didn't use SQL Server Express.

Comment: So is there anyway i can add the database with the setup? I'm really stuck in this and need to find a solution.

Comment: You'll want to use LocalDB, iirc. [Local Data Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms233817(v=vs.110))